# 401 Unauthorized when making request to rails api backend hosted on heroku but works on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am facing a problem where all requests that I make to my backend that requires "before_action :authenticate_request" fails. However, all the requests works on localhost. I am testing my API using insomnia. I have attached the logs below. I have checked out many posts on StackOverflow and other google resources but none of it has worked. I would appreciate any help. Do let me know if I have missed out any important info. I am also using the JWT gem

```
2021-06-22T08:38:07.272841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users" host=tranquil-fjord-90719.herokuapp.com request_id=3e1fbe4f-d487-49ed-9af0-75e451f1d094 fwd="49.245.87.141" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=401 bytes=494 protocol=https
    2021-06-22T08:38:07.270478+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-06-22T08:38:07.270376 #4]  INFO -- : [3e1fbe4f-d487-49ed-9af0-75e451f1d094] Started GET "/users" for 49.245.87.141 at 2021-06-22 08:38:07 +0000
    2021-06-22T08:38:07.271270+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-06-22T08:38:07.271195 #4]  INFO -- : [3e1fbe4f-d487-49ed-9af0-75e451f1d094] Processing by UsersController#index as */*
    2021-06-22T08:38:07.272016+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-06-22T08:38:07.271940 #4]  INFO -- : [3e1fbe4f-d487-49ed-9af0-75e451f1d094] Filter chain halted as :authenticate_request rendered or redirected
    2021-06-22T08:38:07.272206+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-06-22T08:38:07.272134 #4]  INFO -- : [3e1fbe4f-d487-49ed-9af0-75e451f1d094] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.3ms | Allocations: 154)
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    before_action :authenticate_request
    skip_before_action :authenticate_request, :only => [:index]
    attr_reader :current_user

    def index
        render html: '<h1>NUSPM-api</h1>'.html_safe
    end

    private

    def authenticate_request    
        @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
        render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 unless @current_user
    end
end
```

authentication_controller.rb

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_request

    def authenticate
        command = AuthenticateUser.call(params[:email], params[:password])

        if command.success?
            render json: { auth_token: command.result, user: UserRepresenter.new(User.find_by_email(params[:email])).as_json } 
        else
            render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:create]
    before_action :user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:index, :show, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @users = User.all

        render json: UsersRepresenter.new(@users).as_json
    end

    def show
        render json: UserRepresenter.new(@user).as_json
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            token = AuthenticateUser.call(@user.email, @user.password)
            render json: { message: "Account created",
                            token: token,
                            user: UserRepresenter.new(@user).as_json },
                            status: :created
        else
            render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def update
        if @user.update(user_params)
            render json: { message: "Account updated" }, status: :ok
        else
            render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def destroy
        if @user
            @user.destroy
            render json: { message: "Account deleted" }, status: :ok
        else
            render json: { message: "Unable to delete account" }, status: :bad_request
        end
    end

    private

    def user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
        params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) 
    end
end
```

authenticate_user.rb

```
class AuthenticateUser
    prepend SimpleCommand

    def initialize(email, password)
        @email = email
        @password = password
    end

    def call
        JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :email, :password

    def user
        user = User.find_by_email(email)
        return user if user && user.authenticate(password)

        errors.add :user_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
        nil
    end
end
```

authorize_api_request.rb

```
class AuthorizeApiRequest
prepend SimpleCommand

def initialize(headers = {})
    @headers = headers
end

def call
    user
end

private

attr_reader :headers

def user
    @user ||= User.find(decoded_auth_token[:user_id]) if decoded_auth_token
    @user || errors.add(:token, 'Invalid token') && nil
end

def decoded_auth_token
    @decoded_auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
end

def http_auth_header
    if headers['Authorization'].present?
        return headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
    else
        errors.add(:token, 'Missing token')
    end
    nil
end
```

end

Comment: I suggest logging the request headers to verify that the expected Authorization header is there.

Comment: @rmlockerd Hey, thanks for the suggestion! I have checked the headers and I have confirmed that the authorization header is present with the token. Also since I tested the api using insomnia, I can be sure that the jwt is present right? Just to clarify I did test with my front-end as well as insomnia